# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Такое предложение: "Он меняет свое тело(,) как хочет". Нужна тут запятая или нет?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, запятая нужна. Это сложное предложение с придаточным образа действия и союзом как. Второе предложение неполное.